# Apache Thrift and JavaME for BlackBerry Application

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, thrift, thrift-protocol

We are considering using Apache Thrift in a new application we are starting. We do however have some reservations around how well Thrift works in a JavaME environment (since the Thrift documentation is very bad). We have sample applications working in most environments, e.g. server, iPhone and Android, but not BlackBerry (JDE 5.0.0). Has anyone had success in getting it running in a BlackBerry Java application?